# Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Places Library Usage Limits

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have a site that associates Google Place information with users, and displays that information on a map.  For instance, a user can search for a place (currently with the Places Library Autocomplete API) and bookmark this place for later retrieval.

As per the Google Maps TOS, I am only storing the Place ID and its reference in my database and am making client-side requests for the coordinate information of each place whenever I need to display them on a map.

I've recently encountered an issue where making more than 10 consecutive API requests for coordinate information (within a javascript loop) using the getDetails method on the service object returns an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT status code.

My question is this: if I am correct in assuming that storing the latitude and longitude of each place in my database violates Google's TOS, how can I programmatically retrieve the coordinate information for a number of places so that I can display these places on a map for a given user?

Comment: The Places Library is designed to display individual place details on user request therefore there is a limit on the number of queries you can perform per second. 

You might have to rethink your use case so that you don't perform consecutive API requests.

Answer (score 0):

According to the terms - 10.1.3(b) -

(b) No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content. You must not pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: (i) limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily, securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service; and (ii) any content identifier or key that the Maps APIs Documentation specifically permits you to store. For example, you must not use the Content to create an independent database of "places" or other local listings information.

So if there are places getting queried a lot, you can temporarily store information on that place to increase performance.